# Reading a multi-line file that contains varying information that pertains to a particular subclass?

Tags: java, arrays, file, oop, arraylist

So I've developed a method that iterates through a file that may contain different information in each line, then adds them to a generic ArrayList. As you can see in the code I have three subclasses that stems from a superclass Employee; Hourly, Salary, and Commission. I'm just wondering if there is a better way to code this?

Here is my code:

```
public void loadData(File inFile) throws IOException
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner (inFile);
    String employeeName;
    String employeeNum;
    String empDepartment;
    char type;
    while(in.hasNext())
    {
        String employee = in.nextLine();
        String [] employeeList = employee.split(" ");
        //This if reads in an hourly employee
        if(employeeList.length == 6)
        {
            employeeName = employeeList[0];
            employeeNum = employeeList[1];
            empDepartment = employeeList[2];
            type = employeeList[3].charAt(0);
            double hourlyPay = Double.parseDouble(employeeList[4]);
            int hoursWorked = Integer.parseInt(employeeList[5]);
            employees.add(new Hourly(employeeName, employeeNum, empDepartment, type, hourlyPay, hoursWorked));
        }
        //This if reads in a Salary employee
        else if(employeeList.length == 5)
        {
            employeeName = employeeList[0];
            employeeNum = employeeList[1];
            empDepartment = employeeList[2];
            type = employeeList[3].charAt(0);
            double yearlySalary = Double.parseDouble(employeeList[4]);
            employees.add(new Salary(employeeName, employeeNum, empDepartment, type, yearlySalary));
        }
        else if(employeeList.length == 9)
        {
            employeeName = employeeList[0];
            employeeNum = employeeList[1];
            empDepartment = employeeList[2];
            type = employeeList[3].charAt(0);
            int weeksSinceStart = Integer.parseInt(employeeList[4]);
            double baseWklySalary = Double.parseDouble(employeeList[5]);
            double weeklySales = Double.parseDouble(employeeList[6]);
            double totalSales = Double.parseDouble(employeeList[7]);
            double commissionRate = Double.parseDouble(employeeList[8]);
            employees.add(new Commission(employeeName, employeeNum, empDepartment, type, weeksSinceStart, baseWklySalary, weeklySales, totalSales, commissionRate));
        }
    }
    in.close();
}
```

Comment: I think `Hourly`, `Salary` and `Commission` should extend on a separate class say `TermsOfPayment` rather than `Employees` since they are literally not `Employees`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [codereview.se]

Comment: Ohhh okay, I wasn't aware such a section existed. Thanks.

Comment: @Jim Garrison It is okay to recommend the OP post on CR but in the future, please don't use Code Review as a reason to close a question. Evaluate the request and use a reason like *too broad*, *primarily opinion-based*, etc. Then you can mention to the OP that it can be posted on Code Review if it is [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Please see the section **What you should not do** in [this answer to _A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users_](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778/120114)

Comment: Could you change the file input format? If so, I think its better way to use JSON format -- you'd be able to consistently use JSON API to unmarshalling the persistence representation into objects of respective classes.